# How to setup a Facebook API session

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am exploring the Facebook API for a couple of days now, because I am trying to get leads from my Facebook page [using Webhooks with Lead Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5).

After reading a bunch of articles and Facebook documentation I noticed that for a lot functions in the documentation you see a `$session` variable defined (for example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/conversations) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/)).

Because I want to get the leads from my Facebook page I started following this [article](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/), which explains how to get real time lead updates from Facebook.

The article starts with setting up a request for receiving the app subscriptions for your Facebook page. But I directly came into trouble with creating the session, because it looks like the `FacebookSession` class does not exists in the current Facebook SDK anymore.

How do I need to setup this session? Because I can not find anywhere in the SDK files the FacebookSession class, so I think in the mean time this is changed.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

// I cannot find this class anywhere
$session = new FacebookSession('<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>');

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/<APP_ID>/subscriptions',
  array(
    'object' => 'page',
    'callback_url' => '<YOUR_CALLBACK_URL>',
    'fields' => 'conversations',
    'verify_token' => '<YOUR_VERIFY_TOKEN>',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
```

I get an 500 server error with the following message:

**Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found in ...**

Comment: Correct, the FacebookSession calss doesn’t exist any more in the SDK v5. Go check the documentation for FacebookRequest to find out what parameters it wants to get passed in v5.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment. In my opinion it still wants a $session parameter. But I cannot select a version later than 2.5 here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/conversations

Comment: You are confusing API version, and PHP SDK version – those are two completely different things. This is what you should check out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0